# I'm trying to effectively "Index if" - copy a list over with certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of data, and a marker next to it. Think:

ID#1 -- A
ID#2 -- B
ID#3 -- A

I'm trying to move over only the ID numbers with the marker A - so my final result is

ID#1
ID#3

This is very easy to do with VBA - Filter the range, copy, paste. I'm trying to find a non-VBA solution to this problem. I've been trying various array formulas - Index(range,sumproduct(row*criteria)), but I can't quite get it working. How would I get this to work?

Computational elegancy is a significant factor - the sheet I'm dealing with should be a database due to it's size, but the powers that be have nixed that idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$8="A",ROW($B$1:$B$8),999999),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Small will return the IDs with "A" for each row (smallest to largest)
A1:A8 change it to correspond your ID column
B1:B8 change it to correspond your A column
Keep $ for fixed references
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> it is an array formula