# Excel - Extracting values on certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data in Excel with A, B being columns:

```
   A          B         C
Orange      Fruits
Carrots     Vegies
Banana      Fruits
Lettuce     Vegies
Spinach     Vegies
Apples      Fruits
```

I want a formula to extract only "Vegies" from column "A" without empty cells.
So the result should show in "C" only the Vegies, ie, Carrots, Lettuce, Spinach.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try this formula in C1: **=IF(AND(B2="Vegies",A2<>""),A2,"")**

Comment: @Lee:  How is that any better than ``=IF(B2="Vegies",A2,"")``, which p._phidot_ already presented [in an answer](https://superuser.com/q/1509391/150988#1509392), and which isn’t what the question asks for?  And why are you putting a formula in Row 1 that references values in Row 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to effectively "Index if" - copy a list over with certain criteria](https://superuser.com/questions/1221486/im-trying-to-effectively-index-if-copy-a-list-over-with-certain-criteria)

Comment: Similar: *[Listing non-blank cells in Excel based on adjacent column(s)](https://superuser.com/q/748292/150988)* and *[How can I condense a list that has missing data to a new list without the cells with missing data?](https://superuser.com/q/549641/150988)*

Answer (score 1):

Put `=IF(B1="Vegies",A1,"")` in C1, then drag downwards.

Please if it works/not.

note : have a look on how the if() function works in the documentation/help. just ask if you didn't get any part of it. ( :

Comment: Thanks but, with this i will get empty cells. I want the formula to extract and remove empty cells.

Comment: owh.. I missed that in the requirement.. sorry it didn't make it..

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data housed in A1:B6

In C1, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:A$6)/(B$1:B$6="Vegies"),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

Comment: This seems waaaay overengineered for this requirement

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much!